# Reformatting an image colour with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I have a UK map that I've made 15 freeform shapes out of to represent the 15 regions in my company.  On a separate sheet, I have ranked them 1 to 15 based on a certain criteria and have given each of the ranks an RGB colour code to represent their standing (i.e. red would be worst, green best).

I have the below code that I *think* should take the RGB value (in this case it's in cell G2, next region is in G3, then G4 etc) and then change the colour of the corresponding region (called "Freeform 15" in this case) to whatever is in cell G2.  At the moment, it's erroring at the point shown in the code below so I've obviously done something wrong.

Any ideas what I may have missed?  Fyi, I've had the value in G2 as both a lookup and a fixed text field, the result was the same with both - still failing at the same point.

```
Sub FillMap()

Dim FillA As String
FillA = "RGB (" & Sheets("Regional And Divisional").Range("G2").Value & ")"

'Fill Region 1

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Freeform 15")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = FillA  ****Here's where it's failing
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `RGB()` is  a function so it should be `.ForeColor = RGB([Value from cell], [...], [...])`

Comment: OF COURSE!!!  Not sure how I missed that!  I've split the R,G and B out now whereas before I had them all as part of the same string.  Thanks a lot @KostasK., very much appreciated :)